# Discord bot leave and play again something error

Tags: discord, bots

I have a problem. This discord bot can join, play music, pause resune and leave. When i run the bot it can play songs but when i tell him to leave, join again and play something i get this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.

```
music = DiscordUtils.Music()

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx,*,url):
player = music.get_player(guild_id = ctx.guild.id)
if not player:
player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix = True)
if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
await player.queue(url, search = True)
song = await player.play()
else:
song = await player.queue(url, search = True)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def pause(ctx):
player = music.get_player(guild_id = ctx.guild.id)
song = await player.pause()

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
voice = await channel.connect()

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def resume(ctx):
player = music.get_player(guild_id = ctx.guild.id)
song = await player.resume()

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def queue(ctx):
player = music.get_player(guild_id = ctx.guild.id)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```